# Click card to display clone of the card at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Stuck. Not sure how to proceed.

I have 10 cards. When the user clicks on a specific card, I would like to clone the card and have it append to a `div` on top of the page. However, when a user clicks on another card I do not want the first card to disappear, I want it to stay and add the second card next to the first card. Also, want to display a max of 5 cards at the top. If the user clicks on a sixth card, the first should disappear and the clicked card should appear as the last card and so forth.

```js
$('.card').on('click', function() {
  $('.main').slideDown('fast');
  $('.card1').fadeIn(500).clone().appendTo($('.main1'));
  $('.card2').fadeIn(500).clone().appendTo($('.main2'));
  $('.card3').fadeIn(500).clone().appendTo($('.main3'));
  $('.card4').fadeIn(500).clone().appendTo($('.main4'));
  $('.card5').fadeIn(500).clone().appendTo($('.main5'));
});
```

```css
.main { display: none;}

.card {
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="main1"></div>
  <div class="main2"></div>
  <div class="main3"></div>
  <div class="main4"></div>
  <div class="main5"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="card card-1">
    <p>Card 1</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-2">
    <p>Card 2</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-3">
    <p>Card 3</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-4">
    <p>Card 4</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-5">
    <p>Card 5</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <!-- 5 more cards -->
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.card1').fadeIn(500).clone().appendTo($('.main1'));` <-- There is no class `card1`, but `card-1`. the same for cards 2 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with detach() method https://api.jquery.com/detach/

as @Cid  said, use the right class name into jQuery selector .card-1 .card-2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `clone()` and a check to see if `.main` has more than 5 items using `children()`. Please find the snippet below

```js
$('.card').on('click', function() {
  if ($('.main').children().length >= 5) {
    $('.main .card').first().remove();
  }
  $(this).clone().hide().appendTo($('.main')).fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="card card-1">
    <p>Card 1</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-2">
    <p>Card 2</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-3">
    <p>Card 3</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-4">
    <p>Card 4</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-5">
    <p>Card 5</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <!-- 5 more cards -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use childen().first().remove to remove the first one. and then append a new div.

this is a try of what i think you want do

```
<div class="main">
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="card card-1">
        <p>Card 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-2">
        <p>Card 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-3">
        <p>Card 3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-4">
        <p>Card 4</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-5">
        <p>Card 5</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  const main = $('.main')
  const max = 3;
  let count = 0;
  $('.card').on('click', function () {
    main.slideDown();
    if (count < max) count++
    else main.children().first().detach()

    $(this).fadeIn(500).clone().appendTo(main);

  });
})
```